# Android: Dynamically change Image in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview defined by the following xml. I need to **toggle the image** in the list during runtime when the user clicks on any row. How can I achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
//list_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/play" 
android:id="@+id/img"
/> 
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/txt"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can locate the item's `img` view by calling [`findViewById`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) on the second parameter (which is the `View` of the clicked item) within the [`onItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) handler:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parentView, View clickedItemView, int pos, long id)
{
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) clickedItemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Be aware that Android reuses list item `View` objects (also called view recycling), so the toggle state of each item needs to be stored for later use. The toggle state of each item needs to be accessed whenever a list item view is bound to a list item for display.

For example, here is working example of an activity that toggles the image of each item on click:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SO4539968TestCaseActivity extends Activity {
    private static final List<String> ITEM_TEXTS = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"});

    private boolean[] itemToggled;

    private class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
    {
        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            imageView.setImageResource(itemToggled[position] ? R.drawable.on : R.drawable.off);
            return itemView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        itemToggled = new boolean[ITEM_TEXTS.size()];
        Arrays.fill(itemToggled, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view0);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txt, ITEM_TEXTS));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long id) {
                itemToggled[position] = ! itemToggled[position];

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
                imageView.setImageResource(itemToggled[position] ? R.drawable.on : R.drawable.off);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The important parts to study are the `onItemClick` callback and the override of `getView` in `MyArrayAdapter`.

The [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method of the `Adapter` class is responsible for inflating the item layout. In this example, I call the `getView` method of the superclass to initially prepare the item view, but then I make sure to appropriately set the resource ID of the item's `img` view:

```
imageView.setImageResource(itemToggled[position] ? R.drawable.on : R.drawable.off);
```

See also: [Developing Applications for Android – Gotchas and Quirks](https://jonhoo.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/developing-applications-for-android-gotchas-and-quirks/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I was searching for this solution for a very long time, about a month. You saved me :D

Comment: Now, I am able to change the source of the Imageview, but when I scroll below and come back again, the imageview is reset back to its previous source. Why is this happening? Can you help me?

Comment: @Vivek: It sounds like a view reuse problem. Please see my updated answer because I have added a working example and have linked to an excellent blog post that describes Android's recycling of views.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien thanks a lot. This works like magic to me.. I am using this for my imageview which I want to behave like radiobutton.. so how can I make other selected toggle to unselected on item click? plz show me a way to achieve this..

Comment: @Panache: I am not sure what you are asking for. Do you want only one row to show the "selected" image? I.e., if item 1 is "selected", would clicking item 2 select that item *and* deselect item 1?

Comment: @Panache: The code is very similar. Instead of the `itemToggled` array, you would use an `int` member to store the position of the "selected" item. Then, inside `onItemClick` (or `onListItemClick` if using a `ListActivity`), update the `int` member and call `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` on the list view's `MyArrayAdapter<String>` instance. I have working code if you need it. Just ask a new question and I will post it.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien I solved this using your itemToggled[], thanks for your response. In case if required will post another question. One Quick question, I want to show images and text in a different list items. I am able to show the images but the text are not getting bind with the list. I want rows with images and different row for text.

Comment: @Panache: If you want something like http://imgur.com/2dkUZ where the image is on one line and the text on another (but both image and text are part of the same list item view), then you can use [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). If you want two, different list item views—one for the image and another for the text—then one idea is to use something like AWT/Swing's `CardLayout`. A quick Internet search yielded: [Android UI Pattern - Workspaces](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/06/android-ui-pattern-workspaces.html)

Comment: Hi guys, i am facing the same problems. i tried this answer but i am getting null pointer at itemtoggled array. can you please help me with a sample answer based on my stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404273/listview-odd-even-rows-refresh-automatically-when-scrolling-down-or-selecting-an . thanks and regards

Comment: @Dimitri: I am not sure why `itemToggled` would be null. Can you double-check that the member variable is initialized in the onCreate() method? If you update your new question with the full code involving adapting this `itemToggled` array solution, I can take a look.

Answer (score 14):

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            ImageView imageView=arg1.findViewById(R.id.img);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Doesn matter. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I will generate dynamically the listview and then bind to the onclickitem event, in order to do the setimageresource as say by 'Kiril Kirilov'.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done so easily, you need to just look at on the position of list item that was clicked by user. A well described complete demo code is as below_

```
 public class ChangeImageInListDynamically extends Activity {
/**
 * Adapter for your data. 
 */
ImageAdapter adpAR;
ArrayList<String> itemList;
ListView mListView;
ImageAdapter mAdapter;

/**
 * Indicate which item is currently selected.  
 * Its default selected item is '0' e.g., 1st item. 
 */
private int selectedPosition=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        itemList.add("Item - "+i);
    }

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);

    //Initialize your adapter
    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(nChangeImageInListDynamically.this, itemList);

    //set adapter to your list.
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //set list click listener.
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int position, long id) {
            //your image that need to change dynamically.
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.select);

            //position of clicked item.  
            selectedPosition=position;

            //change image of respective image.
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);

            //notify your adapter to update your list.  
            adpAR.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView img;                  
}   

/**
 * Your ImageAdapter.
 */
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> dataList;
    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = arrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataList.size();;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        final ViewHolder holder;
        Log.d("posiiton ImageAdapater : ",""+position);
        if (row == null) { 
            LayoutInflater inflater = ChangeImageInListDynamically.this.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.select);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        //set titel text.
        holder.title.setText(dataList.get(position));

        //Change Image of selected item dynamically.
             if(selectedPosition == position) {
                 //Item is selected.
                 holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);

             }else{
                 //Other non-selected items.
                 holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dis_selected);

             }

        return row;

    }

 }

}
```

I hope this will help to all :)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
public void setImageResource (int resId);
```

method of ImageView class.

P.S. My previous answer seems incomplete, here is the whole solution:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img);
                ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);
                imageView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Here the problem is getting the ImageView. How do I get the corresponding ImageView from the ListView ? When I do **ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;** in OnListItemClick metod i get class cast exception.

Comment: Does this work - ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img);

Comment: No. Because, suppose If I have 40 rows in my listview, All the images will hold the same ID (i.e. img). So we cannot get the handle of selected ImageView with unique ID.

Comment: The ImageView ID is R.id.img, but the drawables can be with different IDs like  R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2...

Comment: Ya. So If I change the source of the image corresponding to R.id.img all the rows in my list are going to get affected right? But I want to change the image in only one row..

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood! I can't help you without the original source where you initialize the whole list.